# Backup huge .tar with low free disk space

Tags: bash, split, pipe, backup, webdav

guys! I have a problem: i need to backup a big folder - 35GB, but i have just a 5 GB free disk space. I think i have in my head right algorithm, but I have little knowledge in bash scripting:

1. Packing with tar
2. Splitting it
3. Get the current splitted filename and upload it via WebDAV
4. Delete it
5. Then split more -> upload an so on

So i think i have to do it with piping |, but i don't know how. Please help me, if you know.

Maybe you know another method.

Comment: Do you have access to remote server via ssh where you want to store your tar files?

Comment: Yes, i have. But my home pc works on Windows. Maybe i have to rsyncing it. Yes, good idea

Comment: is scp usable to copy a file to the destination machine?

Comment: scp will be too slow - there is a website with a tons of images

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am unfamiliar with WebDAV.  I can provide an answer for remote storage of the archive over ssh.  Maybe you can apply this for WebDAV.

To store an archive remotely over ssh, use

```
tar cvf dirToArchive | gzip -c | ssh user@remoteHost 'cat > ~/archive.tgz'
```